# batch conversion of lyx to pdf

Tags: lyx, pdf, conversion

Is it possible to "batch" covert lyx documents to pdf? I have more than 250 lyx docs in a folder. I want them in a pdf format. I can do it manually one by one. But there has to be a better way. Hope there is!

Answer (score 4):

For windows, (untested, I don't have any lyx files), make a batch file `mylyx.bat` with following contents:

```
@ECHO ON
CD /D %~dp0
SET Program="lyx.exe"
for %%A in (*.lyx) do %Program% --export  "pdf2"  %%A
Pause
```

This assumes that `lyx.exe` is in system path. Put the batch file in the samr folder as your lyx files and double click.

Comment: Let me know if it gives trouble :-)

Comment: Ok. Lyx was not in system path. So I added absolute path of lyx.exe to the bat file. Though I can see individual files being processed,   pdf's are not generated. Kindly help.

Comment: @user34083, Can you post the contents of your batch file in your question? Does `lyx --export  "pdf2"  somefile.lyx` work for an individual file? (somefile.lyx is some lyx file.)

Answer (score 1):

On Linux the following will process all .lyx files in the current folder:

```
for i in *.lyx; do lyx -e pdf2 "${i}"; done
```

Or if you want to get fancy, you can process them in parallel with GNU parallel:

```
ls *lyx | parallel --gnu -j3 lyx -e pdf2 {}
```

Note that "pdf2" says to export to PDF with `pdflatex`